# Deductive Reasoning proof logic

Tags: proof-verification, logic, propositional-calculus

I have a question for a deductive reasoning proof i made for the following question: (i needed to prove that these three premises can come to the conclusion of :    ~R <--> ~T Im new to this so im not completely sure that this is correct.

Premises 1-3

1. R--> (S-->T)
2. S
3. ~T

End of Premises --------

4. Sub proof Assumption S
5. Sub proof       T
6. (end of sub proof) S-->T . -->Intro, 4-5
7. R .  --> Elim 1,6
8. T   -->Elim 2,6
9. Sub proof Assumption R
10. Sub proof    T
11. Sub proof  ~T
12. Sub proof  ⊥
13. (end of sub proof)  ~R .  ~Intro, 9-11
14. Sub proof ~R
15. Sub proof    ~T
16. New Sub proof ~T
17. New sub proof   ~R
18. ~R <--> ~T <--> Intro 13-14, 15-16

Comment: Your use of $\to$-elim in step 7 is wrong. You cannot derive $R$ from $R \to (S \to T)$ and $S \to T$.

Answer (score 1):

We have to derive $\lnot R \to \lnot T$ and vice-versa; then conclude with $\leftrightarrow$-intro.

The first part is straightforward, From 3rd premise : $\lnot T$, using $\to$-intro we get immediately:

> 4) $\lnot R \to \lnot T$.

For the second part :

5) $R$ --- temporary assumed for a sub-proof

6) $T$ --- from 5) and 2nd premise from 1st one

7) $\bot$ --- contradicition of 6) with 3rd premise

8) $\lnot R$ --- from 5) and 8) by $\lnot$-intro, discharging temporary assumption.

> 9) $\lnot T \to \lnot R$ --- from 8) by $\to$-intro.
>
> > 10) $\lnot R \leftrightarrow \lnot T$ --- from 4) and 9) by $\leftrightarrow$-intro.

Comment: Ok I see now how you got to step 4 but I dont understand much after that in the second part.

Comment: Oh I didnt know it was possible to go from premise 1 and 3 directly to the  ¬→¬. in line 4

Comment: @Michaellaswhich - NO; from premise 3) only. You can use $\to$-intro because you can assume $\lnot R$ and re-iterate $\lnot T$. Then apply $\to$-intro to get $\lnot R \to \lnot T$, discharging $\lnot R$. It can be abbreviated in this way : $\to$-intro allows to derive $A \to B$ from $B$, with $A$ whatever.